# Two rows of three boxes, need to scale equally

Tags: html, css

So here's my scenario - I need to have two rows of three divs but all six squares need to be touching without border. When I resize the window, I need the 6 boxes to scale with the window proportionally without distorting the aspect ratio of the background image.

So if you scale the image, I need my six boxes to resize proportionally. The width of the section is 100% and the boxes need to fill the entire width.

Can someone recommend a method for this? Here's the HTML I have from that part of the page... not quite sure what to do with the CSS:

```
<section class="cases">
    <div class="row-casebox">
        <div class="casebox">
        </div>
        <div class="casebox">
        </div>
        <div class="casebox">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-casebox">
        <div class="casebox">
        </div>
        <div class="casebox">
        </div>
        <div class="casebox">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-block` to achieve a 3x2 grid with your current markup:

```
.casebox {
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/r8GpH/

Or, you can use `float` to achieve something similar:

```
.casebox {
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQWpB/

**EDIT**

I just re-read your post and the `float` method would probably work best for you seeing as it eliminates spacing between the divs

**EDIT #2**

It sounds like you want the divs to be square at all times so use `vw` units like so:

```
.casebox {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 30vw;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cSAwb/

Comment: I need them to be square and take up the full width... is there any way to do that? I see you've set a static height, but I would need it to be proportional and scale proportionally...

Comment: So they will always be square no matter the screen size?

Comment: Correct, think 3 squares, two rows, no space between, scaling proportionally to stay squares and always taking 100% screen width. I know it's very particular

Comment: @Pete See **EDIT #2** in my answer

Comment: I like the vw solution. Doesn't work with IE8, but I can use an IE specific stylesheet for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to set the casebox properties to a width of 33% and float them left:

```
.casebox{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

There is an example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTbmx/)

Just note that the example contains a border so you can see what's happening. Just remove the border to achieve what you want (which gives you the code I listed above).